# Difference in creating Application object in WPF and WinForms

Tags: wpf, winforms

Why is there a difference in the way the Application object is created in WinForms and WPF?

-> In WinForms we never created the Application object. It was always available (I believe it was Singleton pattern). In WPF, although hidden in App.g.cs we need to instantiate one.

-> In WinForms it was a sealed class, but in WPF the way to go is to inherit it.

Is this done:

- to be able to define the application in Xaml (App.xaml)
- due to introduction xbap/navigation projects?

What benefits does it really provide?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that the design decision is *entirely* motivated by the desire to be able to define the `Application` object in XAML.  But that's reason enough, it seems to me.